# (iPhone) -How to use built-in mic if Headset is plugged in?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I am working with audio-sessions in iOS and I want to route the audio input to the built in mic of the iPhone even if an external headset is plugged in. Any suggestion how to do this.

Comment: what are you trying to do. more details would be good....

Comment: I want to force the device to continue using the phone's inbuilt mic, when a headset is connected.

Comment: I also gone through Handling Audio Hardware Route Changes documentation provided by apple but its not so helpful. thanks